# find the total distance of point on x axis in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic, axis

I am creating a program in JavaScript that will detect the line is in parallel to x or Y axis so here I want to distance of 5+3-2=6 for total distance but here I get the distance of 5+3=8 and 5-2=3 so how to do like that I will get the result like 5+3-2.code is given below

```
let points = [
    [3, 3],
    [3, 5],
    [3, -2]
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
    if (points[i][0] !== points[i + 1][0]) {
      console.log("|| to Y and distance");
    } else if (points[i][1] !== points[i + 1][1]) {
      console.log("|| to X and distance",points[i+1][1]+points[i][1]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let points = [  [3, 3],
  [3, 5],
  [3, -2]
];

let totalDistance = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < points.length-1; i++) {
  if (points[i][0] !== points[i + 1][0]) {
    console.log("|| to Y and distance");
    totalDistance += Math.abs(points[i + 1][0] - points[i][0]);
  } else if (points[i][1] !== points[i + 1][1]) {
    console.log("|| to X and distance");
    totalDistance += Math.abs(points[i + 1][1] - points[i][1]);
  }
}
console.log("Total distance:", totalDistance);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the hypothenuse and add the values.

```js
let points = [[3, 3], [3, 5], [3, -2]],
    distance = 0;
  
for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
    distance += Math.hypot(
        points[i - 1][0] - points[i][0],
        points[i - 1][1] - points[i][1]
    );
}

console.log(distance);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to measure the parallel distances where two points share the same x/y values, you can try the following.

**Note:** To make the logic easier to follow, I convert the incoming coordinates matrix into an array of (x, y) point objects.

```js
const calculateParallelDistances = (coordinatesArr) => {
  const points = coordinatesArr.map(([x, y]) => ({ x, y }));
  let totalDistance = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
    const currPoint = points[i], nextPoint = points[i + 1];
    if (currPoint.y === nextPoint.y) {
      console.log("|| to Y and distance");
      totalDistance += Math.abs(nextPoint.x - currPoint.x);
    } else if (currPoint.x === nextPoint.x) {
      console.log("|| to X and distance");
      totalDistance += Math.abs(nextPoint.y - currPoint.y);
    }
  }
  return totalDistance;
};

let distance = calculateParallelDistances([[3, 3], [3, 5], [3, -2]]);
console.log("Total distance:", distance);
```